# Office 365 and PHPMailer unable to log in

Tags: php, office365, phpmailer

I am attempting to configure php to send email's through office 365, but I get a authentication error

```
17-09-08 16:43:00   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2017-09-08 16:43:00    SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 XXREMOVEDXX 2017-09-08 16:43:00   CLIENT
-> SERVER: 334 XXREMOVEDXX 2017-09-08 16:43:00  SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 XXREMOVEDXX 2017-09-08 16:43:00   CLIENT -> SERVER: 334 XXREMOVEDXX 2017-09-08 16:43:06   SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MWHPR11CA0014.namprd11.prod.outlook.com] 2017-09-08 16:43:06   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MWHPR11CA0014.namprd11.prod.outlook.com] 2017-09-08 16:43:06    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2017-09-08 16:43:06 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2017-09-08 16:43:06  SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel 2017-09-08 16:43:06    Connection: closed 2017-09-08 16:43:06  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.' in /PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php:1697 Stack trace:
#0 /fast/home/tholum/mailtest/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php(1540): PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)
#1 /fast/home/tholum/mailtest/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php(1335): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Fri, 8 Se...', 'This is a multi...')
#2 /fast/home/tholum/mailtest/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php(1213): PHPMailer->postSend()
#3 /fast/home/tholum/mailtest/test2.php(25): PHPMailer->send()
#4 {main}
```

The code I am attempting to send from is

```
<?php
require_once("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$emailLogin="My-Email@mydomain.com"; //Username and Password work from web
$emailPassword='MyPassword';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username = $emailLogin;
$mail->Password = $emailPassword;
$mail->SetFrom($emailLogin, 'FromEmail');
$mail->addAddress('anotherEmail@anotherdomain.com', 'ToEmail');
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
//$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {echo "debug level $level; message: $str";}; //$mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: No one is going to debug your code for you. Are you sure the Office365 API allows for plaintext password auth like this? Check the API docs for how they recommend you do this, and check the docs for the error code regarding the password.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without the whole SMTP transcript (minus your encoded password).

Comment: Stack overflow wouldnt let me add it to the post ( to high of a % of code )
https://pastebin.com/0JXfv4Ks

Answer (score 1):

To force password as a plain text use:
`$mail->AuthType = "PLAIN";`

other options: CRAM-MD5, PLAIN, LOGIN, XOAUTH2
more info: https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.SMTP.html